# Bundling and Minification mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundle

I create a mvc4 application for test Bundling and Minification but when i run it and look html rendered code I noticed
no my css and javascript are not Bundle

```
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

but by default visual studio added in my layout file

```
   @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css", "~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
```

so i want to know why css and javascript are not  Bundle?

Comment: See  http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification you are in debug mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get the same thing. When I change my web.config to this though:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5" />
    ...
</system.web>
```

...it instead renders this:

```
<link href="/Content/themes/base/css?v=ps9Ga9601PrzNA2SK3sQXlYmNW3igUv5FOdOPWptyus1"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/Content/css?v=VvXiCiApDAv4OzD9Y7PEaTL0kONCWIV6Skw7uh51PZk1" 
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: correct. It's all in my tutorial  http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification

Answer (score 0):

```
 BundleTable.EnableOptimization = true;
```

Add this line of code in Application_Start() method in Global.asax.cs. This will override any setting from web.config and enable optimization.
For more details [Refer](http://modernpathshala.com/Forum/Thread/Interview/7158/bundling-and-minification-in-mvc) video tutorial of how to implement Bundling and Minification